# I have a parent widget that contains multiple child widgets which each include a checkbox. How can I check every checkbox from the parent widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a parent widget that draws multiple child widgets using a listview. There is a checkbox within each of these child widgets. I am trying to implement a "select all" button in the parent widget which checks all of the children's checkboxes, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this.

Here is my parent widget:

```
class OrderDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/orderDisplay';
  //final Order order;
  //const OrderDisplay(this.order);

  @override
  OrderDisplayState createState() {
    return OrderDisplayState();
  }
}

class OrderDisplayState extends State<OrderDisplay> {
  bool preChecked = false;
  double total = 0;
  List<OrderedItem> itemsToPayFor = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final OrderDisplayArguments args =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(args.order.restaurantName,
                            style: MyTextStyles.headingStyle),
                        ListView.separated(
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: args.order.orderedItems.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return FoodOrderNode(
                                  preChecked, args.order.orderedItems[index],
                                  onCheckedChanged: (isChecked) {
                                isChecked
                                    ? setState(() {
                                        itemsToPayFor.add(
                                            args.order.orderedItems[index]);
                                      })
                                    : setState(() {
                                        itemsToPayFor.remove(
                                            args.order.orderedItems[index]);
                                      });
                              });
                            },
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                MyDividers.MyDivider)
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            MyDividers.MyDivider,
            Container(
                height: 140,
                color: MyColors.backgroundColor,
                child: Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 5,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(flex: 2, child: SizedBox()),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 6,
                              child: SelectAllButton(() {
                                print("SELECT ALL");
                                setState(() {
                                  preChecked = true;
                                });
                              })), 
                          Expanded(flex: 2, child: SizedBox())
                        ],
                      )),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 5,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 8,
                              child: PayNowButton(() {
                                print("PAY NOW");
                              },
                                  double.parse(itemsToPayFor
                                      .fold(0, (t, e) => t + e.itemPrice)
                                      .toStringAsFixed(
                                          2)))),
                          Expanded(flex: 1, child: SizedBox())
                        ],
                      ))
                ]))
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

And here is `FoodOrderNode`:

```
typedef void SelectedCallback(bool isChecked);

class FoodOrderNode extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool preChecked;
  final OrderedItem item;
  final SelectedCallback onCheckedChanged;

  const FoodOrderNode(this.preChecked, this.item,
      {@required this.onCheckedChanged});

  @override
  FoodOrderNodeState createState() {
    return FoodOrderNodeState();
  }
}

class FoodOrderNodeState extends State<FoodOrderNode> {
  bool isChecked = false;
  bool isSplitSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isChecked = widget.preChecked;
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: MyColors.nodeBackgroundColor,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: CircularCheckBox(
                value: isChecked,
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                autofocus: false,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  print("Change to val: $value");
                  widget.onCheckedChanged(value);
                  setState(() {
                    isChecked = value;
                  });
                },
              )),
          Expanded(
            flex: 7,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 40),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.item.itemName,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    )),
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                    child: Text(
                      "\$${widget.item.itemPrice}",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: MyColors.labelColor),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: isSplitSelected
                  ? SplitButtonSelected(() {
                      setState(() {
                        isSplitSelected = false;
                      });
                    })
                  : SplitButtonUnselected(() {
                      setState(() {
                        isSplitSelected = true;
                      });
                    }))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried creating a "preChecked" argument for FoodOrderNode and then using setState from the parent widget, however, that hasn't worked out. I have also tried using keys, but I couldn't figure out how to get those working for this either. Thank you, and let me know if you'd like any more relevant code.

Comment: May this be helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672884/tick-subcategories-when-a-category-is-selected/71723969#:~:text=tristate.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_parentValue%20%3D%20null-,%3B,-%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Yes.%20Select

Answer (score 0):

Just put a global checkbox above the list items and give it `isAllChecked` (bool) on its value so when it will be checked set the state to `isAllChecked` => true and then in child checkboxes check for condition if `isAllChecked` is true then mark as `true` or checked.

`GlobalCheckbox(
     onChanged(value){
      setState(()
      {
       isAllChecked==value;
      });
     }
    );`


    `ChildCheckBox(
     value: isAllChecked ? true : false
    )`

this might help you:)

Comment: That's something I already tried a bit of - I gave `FoodOrderNode` an argument called `bool preChecked` so I could update every node via setState from the parent widget, but my issue was in having it update. Would you have an idea on how to update this?

Comment: Dont give arguement to listview, instead try without arguement on setState, or can you provide full dart code

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I'm not giving an argument to Listview (unless you're talking about all of the necessary stuff in order to use Listview). I've posted both full files of code if it gives you any more context.