# Tick subcategories when a category is selected

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a filter box icon that opens a dialog box with categories and subcategories when clicked. As follows:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I would like to make it so that when a user checks a category (in my case it is a country), all subcategories (in my case it is a city) are automatically checked (yes, from the point of view of a database search, this does not matter in most cases, but for user looks prettier).
Can you tell me if this can be done in my code?

filter_dialog.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'custom_checkbox_tile.dart';

const georgia = [
  'Georgia',
];

const georgiaCities = [
  'Tbilisi',
  'Batumi',
];



class FilterDialogUser extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(Map<String, List<String>?>) onApplyFilters;

  final Map<String, List<String>?> initialState;

  const FilterDialogUser({
    Key? key,
    required this.onApplyFilters,
    this.initialState = const {},
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterDialogUser> createState() => _FilterDialogUserState();
}

class _FilterDialogUserState extends State<FilterDialogUser> {
  Map<String, List<String>?> filters = {};
  bool isClickedGeorgia = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filters = widget.initialState;
  }

  void _handleCheckFilter(bool checked, String key, String value) {
    final currentFilters = filters[key] ?? [];
    if (checked) {
      currentFilters.add(value);
    } else {
      currentFilters.remove(value);
    }
    setState(() {
      filters[key] = currentFilters;


    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text('Filters',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: 'SuisseIntl',
            )),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),

        // Defining parameters for filtering.
        children: [
          Column(
            children: georgia.map(
                  (e) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          isClickedGeorgia = !isClickedGeorgia;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          CustomCheckboxTile(
                            value: filters['georgia']?.contains(e) ?? false,
                            onChange: (check) => _handleCheckFilter(
                                check, 'georgia', e),
                            label: e,
                          ),

                          const Spacer(),
                          isClickedGeorgia
                              ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up)
                              : const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    !isClickedGeorgia
                        ? Container()
                        : Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: georgiaCities.map((e) {
                          return Row(children: [
                            CustomCheckboxTile(
                              value:
                              filters['georgiaCities']?.contains(e) ??
                                  false,
                              onChange: (check) => _handleCheckFilter(
                                  check, 'georgiaCities', e),
                              label: e,
                            ),
                          ]);
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ).toList(),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: From your code snip, you're checking `isClickedGeoriga` then showing subcategories of it and the `CustomCheckboxTile` is passed with value false as default?  I think you can add another inline condition to check if the parent cat. is selected by default then make the subs. value to `true`

Comment: you might be help from this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71672881/9372923

Comment: Can multiple countries be selected? and can the user unselect/select cities afterward?

Comment: @NarendraBhatt 
Yes, of course, the user should still be able to select several countries (I removed the part of the code that describes other countries).
Yes, and I would like that after the user selects a country, all the cities of this country are selected, the user has the opportunity to deselect any city.

Comment: @NarendraBhatt Similar to the example in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBO_Y8fTM7E

Comment: @Павел this might be helpful!
https://medium.com/@nishsvn.dev/flutter-parent-and-child-checkboxes-part-2-98ce62156004

Answer (score 3):

```
class _ParentChildCheckboxesState extends State<ParentChildCheckboxes> {
  bool _parentValue;
  List<String> _children;
  List<bool> _childrenValue;
void _manageTristate(int index, bool value) {
    setState(() {
      if (value) {
        // selected
        _childrenValue[index] = true;
        // Checking if all other children are also selected -
        if (_childrenValue.contains(false)) {
          // No. Parent -> tristate.
          _parentValue = null;
        } else {
          // Yes. Select all.
          _checkAll(true);
        }
      } else {
        // unselected
        _childrenValue[index] = false;
        // Checking if all other children are also unselected -
        if (_childrenValue.contains(true)) {
          // No. Parent -> tristate.
          _parentValue = null;
        } else {
          // Yes. Unselect all.
          _checkAll(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  ...
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _children.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => CustomLabeledCheckbox(
            label: _children[index],
            value: _childrenValue[index],
            onChanged: (value) {
              _manageTristate(index, value);
            },
            checkboxType: CheckboxType.Child,
            activeColor: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

For better reference refer below link.
https://medium.com/@nishsvn.dev/flutter-parent-and-child-checkboxes-part-2-98ce62156004

Comment: Thanks, I'm already reading and trying to figure it out.
Could you help me connect this code to mine. I have been writing on a flatter for a couple of months, while this is a difficult task for me

Comment: try this one!
val parentValue = filters['georgia']?.contains(e) ?? false
CustomCheckboxTile(
                                    value: if(parentValue) true else if(filters['georgiaCities']?.contains(e) ??
                                            false) else false
                                     ,
                                    onChange: (check) => _handleCheckFilter(
                                        check, 'georgiaCities', e),
                                    label: e,
                                  ),

Comment: or am i doing something wrong or it doesn't work

Comment: Try to understand the above mentioned code and link it will help.As your code is not wrong but it does not provide any parent data to child.

Comment: @Павел

try this one! val parentValue = filters['georgia']?.contains(e) ?? false CustomCheckboxTile( value: if(parentValue) true else if(filters['georgiaCities']?.contains(e) ?? false) else false , onChange: (check) => _handleCheckFilter( check, 'georgiaCities', e), label: e, ),

Comment: @Павел
Please let me know if my answer helped you out. If so, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer  If you still have questions, feel free to ask 

Comment: Your answer did not help me unfortunately. The compiler underlines this code with a red line. Perhaps you can show me how to connect your part to my code.

Comment: Please provide me full snippet of your code.

Comment: I updated my code one minute ago. Thank you that you try help me!!

Comment: @Павел
Please provide me calling widget FilterDialogUser(onApplyFilters:) code.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. I have added code to my code. Now I'll be in touch

Answer (score 0):

When `isClickedGeorgia` is true you're showing its sublists and to make it also selected, you can pass the `value` property of `CustomCheckboTile` to true by default.

```
 !isClickedGeorgia
    ? Container()
    : Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Column(
          children: georgiaCities.map((e) {
            return Row(children: [
              CustomCheckboxTile(
                value:
                    isClickedGeorgia ? true : filters['georgiaCities']?.contains(e),
                onChange: (check) => _handleCheckFilter(
                    check, 'georgiaCities', e),
                label: e,
              ),
            ]);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
```

Also, am not sure about this cause how `CustomCheckboxTile` is written, if possible you can share that code snippet too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in this case, all subcategory items are initially displayed with a check mark.
(I added to my code what you asked for)

Comment: You mean all countries' subcategory is checked too.

Comment: I did not quite understand your question: in my case, the category is the country, the subcategory is cities. And I would like if the user clicks on the country (category), then the cities (subcategory) in this country were marked with checkmarks.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Didn't the above method work? It'll make the ciites too auto checked if country is selected

Comment: With this approach, the elements of the subcategory initially become with a check mark when opened, moreover, without the ability to remove the check marks